# Test push notification with production apns

Tags: ios, testing, notifications, push, production

I need to test the push notification with the APNs production also compiling the app with the certificate adhoc, currently the app is in state "waiting for review" there is a way to test the Push notification with production apns?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can try to create a production profile and sign the app with this one.
After you could try pus notification

Comment: I have already tried using the production profile and the profile adhoc appstore and does not work with the developer profile works.